# Callout Popup is not working in App Part

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app

I have to display a popup as in SharePoint 2013 which is called Callout popup. for that I have to use callout.js file in my code.

I have tried it with Content Editor Web part and it is working fine but when I tried to use it in my App Part it is not working Correctly it is giving me following Error.

**SCRIPT5009: 'IsElementRtl' is undefined

callout.js, line 1 character 8584**

NOTE : I have tried following links.

[Learningsharepoint Post](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/30/the-new-hover-overpreviewcallout-popups-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[Alex Boev Blog](http://blog.alexboev.com/2012/07/custom-callouts-in-sharepoint-2013.html)

[Anatoly's Blog](http://chuvash.eu/2012/10/11/callouts-in-sharepoint-2013-preview/#comment-1275)

I have added following JS references in My App Part

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/mQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/callout.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. the problem was I have not referenced all the files that are needed to referenced.
I referenced like below and it worked for me :)

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/initstrings.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/strings.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/core.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/mQuery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/callout.js"></script>

Comment: I've done a little additional research now for the autohosted apps - here's the post and the working sample ASP.Net project: [link](http://blog.alexboev.com/2013/04/custom-callouts-in-sharepoint-2013.html). My app setup is almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

first see if its happning on all browsers? try it on more than one pc to see if its only a local issue!

before you do the above try moving the imports so that the first reference is callout.js

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/callout.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/mQuery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

what i get from the error is your trying to use callout.js method before its referenced? so by putting it first we can see if it solves your issue

Comment: Thanks Ali,
I tried that also but it didn't helped me. I found the solution. there was reference of some JS files were missing.

Answer (score -1):

Nice Post.

I have also modified the Feedback Callout popup [here](http://asharepointsolutions.blogspot.in/2013/08/create-quick-contact-us-or-feedback.html).
May It help to others also.